# Getting rows with same or different logical values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators

I have a dataframe of two columns of T and F.
I want to know

1. which row is T in the first and F in the second
2. which row is F in the first and T in the second
3. which row is F in both

I have very little clues on the matter, con someone shine a light?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case when`

```r
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(x = c("T","T","F","F","F"), y = c("T","F","T","F","X"))

df %>%
  mutate(condition = case_when(
    x == "T" & y == "T" ~ "Both are T",
    x == "T" & y == "F" ~ "First is T fecond is F",
    x == "F" & y == "F" ~ "Both are F",
    x == "F" & y == "T" ~ "First is F, second is T",
    TRUE ~ "Something else"
  ))
#>   x y               condition
#> 1 T T              Both are T
#> 2 T F  First is T fecond is F
#> 3 F T First is F, second is T
#> 4 F F              Both are F
#> 5 F X          Something else
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It works just fine. I forget to mention that they are logical, but it is a minor nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = rep(c(T, F, T, F), each=2),
                 b = rep(c(T, T, F, F), each=2))

#       a     b
# 1  TRUE  TRUE
# 2  TRUE  TRUE
# 3 FALSE  TRUE
# 4 FALSE  TRUE
# 5  TRUE FALSE
# 6  TRUE FALSE
# 7 FALSE FALSE
# 8 FALSE FALSE

df %>% 
  mutate(newcol = case_when(a & !b ~ "first=T second=F",
                            !a & b ~ "first=F second=T",
                            !a & !b ~ "both=F",
                            TRUE ~ "other"))

#       a     b           newcol
# 1  TRUE  TRUE            other
# 2  TRUE  TRUE            other
# 3 FALSE  TRUE first=F second=T
# 4 FALSE  TRUE first=F second=T
# 5  TRUE FALSE first=T second=F
# 6  TRUE FALSE first=T second=F
# 7 FALSE FALSE           both=F
# 8 FALSE FALSE           both=F
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat `[a,b]` columns as a 2-bit binary number vector, and `a*2+b` transfer it from binary to decimal. Thus, `2*a+b+1` is mapped to `1,2,3,4`.

Try the base R code below

```
transform(
  df,
  newcol = c("both=F", "first=F,second=T", "first=T,second=F", "other")[a * 2 + b + 1]
)
```

which gives

```
      a     b           newcol
1  TRUE  TRUE            other
2  TRUE  TRUE            other
3 FALSE  TRUE first=F,second=T
4 FALSE  TRUE first=F,second=T
5  TRUE FALSE first=T,second=F
6  TRUE FALSE first=T,second=F
7 FALSE FALSE           both=F
8 FALSE FALSE           both=F
```

## Data

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(c(T, F, T, F), each=2),
                 b = rep(c(T, T, F, F), each=2))
```

Comment: I'd reallly prefer go by basic R. but I didn't get what the `[a * 2 + b + 1]` part do or how it works. I gather these are the column name, but the operating logic still baffles me.

Comment: @Alkaligrass You can treat `[a,b]` columns as a 2-bit binary number vector, and `a*2+b` transfer it from binary to decimal. In this case `2*a+b+1` is mapped to `1,2,3,4`.

Comment: Thankss for the explanation! I think I can use this strategy for other ends too!